# Touchpad mouse stopped working after partition changes

Tags: 10.04, hardware, mouse

Because my ubuntu partion was to small, I have enlarged it with the Ubuntu LiveCD + GParted.

All went fairly well (it said there were 2 warnings, but nothing severly), but afterwards, after I have logged in, the touchpad stops working.

Strange thing is, in the login screen, it still works perfectly, and an external USB mouse also works.

I have a HP DV6 2030sd laptop with Ubuntu 10.04 installed.

Does anyone know what steps I can take to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you try to login as an other user? (if you press ctrl+alt+f1 you will get to a console login prompt, there you can create a user with the command `sudo adduser NewUserName`) This will eliminate the possibility that some of you users configuration have been screwed up!

Comment: Is there any data in `/var/log/messages` or the like about an input issue?

Comment: My touchpad never works when a USB mouse is plugged in. Could that be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working after switching the hardware enable/disable touchpad button.